# how to get previous value in a fact table for a measure in mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube, mdx-query

I want to write an mdx query with a calculated Measure.
Here is my fact table:

[image: my case]

How to implement a mesaure with the rule below :

If CurrentAtt != PreviousAtt then PreviousValue

else CurrentValue

Thank you so much!

any suggestion please   ?

Comment: Hi Tarikqazza - I think people will help you but you need to first have a go at creating MDX query yourself and then post your attempt in here

Answer (score 0):

There are functions `PrevMember` and `MemberValue` in `MDX` that you could use.

To implement the logic you could use `IIF`

So something like the following:

```
IIF(
[Attrib].CURRENTMEMBER.MemberValue <> [Attrib].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER.MemberValue
, ([Attrib].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER, [Mesure1])
, ([Attrib].CURRENTMEMBER, [Mesure1])
)
```